# Does Fabric support queries on views?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The fabric chaincode supports the couchdb **/db/_find** API via the QueryDocuments function.

Is there similar support for CouchDB **/db/_design/design-doc/_view/view-name** API for querying views inside the chaincode?

Couldnt find anthing here : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/13447bf5ead693f07285ce63a1903c5d0d25f096/core/ledger/util/couchdb/couchdb.go

Answer (score 2):

There is a jira issue open to add support for this sometime in the future but there is no schedule for when it will be done.

See https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5528